# SQL query to find all records that have duplicates in one column without grouping

Tags: sql

I am not working directly with SQL so I'm a bit limited.

The filters on the program I'm using use SQL but basically functions as a 
`select * where` statement then whatever input I give.

I have a list of records and I need to pull each record with a duplicate so the below table will return `WO#` 1 and 3 with all associated columns:

```
+------+----------+---------------+------------+-------+
| WO#  |    Site  |    Customer   |    Date    |  ...  |
+------+----------+---------------+------------+-------+
| 1    |    X     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
| 2    |    Y     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
| 3    |    X     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
| 4    |    Z     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
| 5    |    A     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
| 6    |    B     |    ABC        |   1/5/2018 |       |
+------+----------+---------------+------------+-------+
```

Am I trying to do something impossible without grouping?

Comment: Depends if your program accounts for SQL injection ;-)

Comment: Well that table didn't turn out  how i expected.  I'm new... if someone can help me with format of tables I'll get it fixed!

Comment: Which column do you want to check for duplicates, just the `Site` column?

Comment: Haha, Lee Mac, no it doesn't.

Comment: @Nicholas Smith - Yes

Comment: I'd just export to Excel and filter there.  Without knowing all the limitations of that software at least.

Comment: This is what grouping is for.  If you can't do that then the SQL you're using is extremely limited and providing further insight is fairly essential if you want a decent answer.

Comment: Do you have the ability to do sub-selects or anything in your where clause? What are you actually limited to?

Comment: @n8. Unfortunately I'm figuring out the limitations as I go.  I see your point though, I'm really throwing a Hail Mary while I wait for a response from the software's tech support here.  Was hoping there's a Query that just say something like "Pull all records where you see duplicates within a field".

Comment: @NicholasSmith I believe I can, I just can't do any joins or interact with other tables, I'm at least limited to anything that can come after "select * where" but it doesn't seem that i can group by (at least the statement can't start with group by... that's for sure)

Comment: It seems like your best bet is as Aaron suggests, extract the data and perform your dupe check external of the software that's bottlenecking you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an `EXISTS` could work to find the dups?

```
select * 
from yourtable t
where exists
( 
   select 1
   from yourtable d
   where d.Site = t.Site and d.WO# != t.WO#
);
```

Comment: I can't interact with another table though... am i reading this wrong?  Would I need to?

Comment: @CyrusNaser Well, it's basically only using 1 table, twice.  What it does is only selecting those from the table where there exists another record with the same Site value.  You didn't name your table, so I just named it 'yourtable' for the example.

Comment: you're right, but it's still referencing "another table" which I haven't gotten to work.  I can't define D and T the way you do above... though i like the thinking.

Comment: But not even having the ability to use the same table could be a problem. There are similar methods like f.e. using an `IN` but that also requires to select from the same table twice.  And if your database supports the window functions then you could do something with a `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY Site)`, but that could also require a sub-query.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be right.  I'll respond when I hear back from technical support with the answer.